# Create a Matrix out of two matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have two matrices `A = {{a1,a2},{b1,b2}}` and `B = {{x1,x2},{y1,y2}}`. I would like to create out of these matrices a new matrix `C={{{a1,x1},{a2,x2}},{{b1,y1},{b2,y2}}}` which I would like at the end transform to this form `{{a1,x1},{a2,x2},{b1,y1},{b2,y2}}`. Of course, I am looking for a solution to the general case. Thanks.

Comment: I have a problem when B is a vector not a matrix, both procedures below do not work. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
a = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}; b = {{x1, x2}, {y1,  y2}};
```

Then

```
Transpose[{Flatten[a], Flatten[b]}]

{{a1, x1}, {a2, x2}, {b1, y1}, {b2, y2}}
```

gives you the form you want.

Comment: Thanks; simple and to the point!

Comment: I have problem when b={x,y}; the procedure that you suggested does not work. Is there any way around it?

Comment: If `a` is a matrix and `b` is a vector, what do you want the answer to be?

Comment: Suppose a = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}}; b = {x, y}; I want to obtain {{a1, a2,x}, {b1, b2,y}}. Thanks.

Comment: Probably not too generalizable, but `Partition[Flatten[Riffle[a, b]], 3]` gives you the answer you want.

Answer (score 2):

We can go for this

```
a = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}};
b = {{x1, x2}, {y1, y2}};
MapThread[{#1, #2} &, Flatten /@ {a, b}]
```

> {{a1, x1}, {a2, x2}, {b1, y1}, {b2, y2}}

If you persist on having a `c` you can do this

```
Partition[Transpose[Flatten /@ {a, b}], Length@b]
```

> {{{a1, x1}, {a2, x2}}, {{b1, y1}, {b2, y2}}}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually the first one is fine. I don't need intermediate results. Thanks Plato. :) //Nietzsche.

Answer (score 2):

You only need flatten:

```
Flatten[{A, B}, {{2, 3}, {1}}]
```

> {{a1, x1}, {a2, x2}, {b1, y1}, {b2, y2}}

Comment: Nice to see `Flatten[]`!

Answer (score 0):

Two more alternatives:

```
Thread[Flatten /@ {a, b}]
Inner[List, Flatten@a, Flatten@b, List]
```

> {{a1, x1}, {a2, x2}, {b1, y1}, {b2, y2}}